# Dropdownlist inside a Gridview

Tags: javascript

HI,
i am working on dropdownlist inside datagrid if i select one value in any row of dropdowlist 
then if i am select same value in another row of a dropdown then display message 'already added'.

**How to do this using javascript**

Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you reconsider your UI; it seems you are asking your user to choose x of y items, and I would likely not choose a grid with pulldown widgets to implement that functionality.

Regardless, maintain an object to indicate those items selected by the user (selected['purple'] = true) and examine this object (if selected['purple'] === true) to determine whether to display your message.

Good luck!